# Attempt to invoke interface method android

Tags: java, android

i have this code in  class  `A`

```
 private RtcListener mListener;

@Override
public void Update(String string) {
    //here its work now i want to pass data to Interface 

        mListener.onUpdate(sometext);


}


public interface RtcListener{

    void onUpdate(String string);

}
```

now in another class and its `B`

> i implements the Interface

```
public class B extends Service implements A.RtcListener{

// here i Override interface method
  @Override
public void onUpdate(String string) {

 Log.d("dwdwadwadwd"," the data is"+string);

}



}
```

its give me the error

```
 Attempt to invoke interface method 'void .....  on a null object reference
```

Comment: @quidproquo thats answer work with activity and service not with class none activity

Comment: That's not how you would usually communicate with a Service, you should use LocalBroadcastManager or an EventBus.

Comment: Your mListener is null

Comment: @OneStepBack yes thats the problem and i solve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by do this in class `B`

construct the class

A in class B

```
A myclass = new A(this,another prameter if u have,another prameter if u have);
```

and in class `A` on construct function i do this

```
public A(RtcListener l , other prameter , other prameter){ //construct method //RtcListener  its your interface name
mListener = l;
}
```

> just be sure your code interface like my code above in question also
>   the implements

that's all :)